# Creating a Query for SQL Server (using SQL Developer)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

Both these queries run perfectly when they are separate.  However when I try to combine it into one query is when I'm getting problems.  Can anyone suggest a code with the proper syntax for it to run in Oracle SQL Developer.

First Query:

```
 select * from JnlDataSection, JnlList, JnlMedium, JnlMediumMove
 where 
 JnlDataSection.ItemID = JnlList.ItemID AND
 JnlList.ItemID = JnlMedium.ItemID AND
 JnlMedium.ItemID = JnlMediumMove.ItemID;
```

Second Query (This needs to be incorporated in the First Query):

```
 UserCode = 'Automation' AND     
 LEFT(Date,8)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112));
```

---

Note: I am using a Microsoft SQL Server Database on Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine" and what are the "problems" you've encountered. Please provide an example of what you have tried.

Comment: By combine I mean I want to display all the data thats in those four tables with the UserCode = Automation and the Date to which I specified.  UserCode and Date are both common keys between the four tables.

Comment: The second code snippet (which is **not** a query) is not valid for Oracle. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: The second query works for any given table..

For example
Select * from JnlDataSection
where  UserCode = 'Automation' AND     
 LEFT(Date,8)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112));

Comment: I am using an SQL Database on SQL Oracle Developer.

Comment: you can paste some data of all four tables. It will show the data structure as well and with this you can provide your desired result also.
it would be very helpful to look into your problem.

Comment: ok I will post a sample row

Comment: When I run the first query I get this and many more columns:
ItemID=1223
Date=20120927.185318213
Object=Backup
MsgID=61
UserCode=Unspecified

Comment: If you're using an non-Oracle database you should make that explicitly clear in your question, my giving the flavour and version.  Tagging your question with [oracle] is confusing and annoying, because people waste their time answering the wrong question.

Comment: Also, please *edit your question* to add pertinent information rather than burying it in the comments.

Comment: With "SQL Database" do you actually mean "Microsoft SQL Server"? Any current relational DBMS is a "*SQL database*" because SQL is only a query language it is ***not*** a DBMS product.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your comments correctly, all four of the tables being joined contain columns named `UserCode` and `Date`.  So I expect that you are getting an error because the parser can't tell which table's columns you are referring to.  You would have to qualify them like:

```
select * from JnlDataSection, JnlList, JnlMedium, JnlMediumMove
 where 
 JnlDataSection.ItemID = JnlList.ItemID AND
 JnlList.ItemID = JnlMedium.ItemID AND
 JnlMedium.ItemID = JnlMediumMove.ItemID AND
 JnlDataSection.UserCode = 'Automation' AND     
 LEFT(JnlDataSection.Date,8)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112)
```

Without knowing your database design, I don't know if you should add these conditions on all four tables, or just one, or if it matters which one.

Comment: I have added the necessary AND there but now the query is running error free but no data is being displayed, it is just an empty display.

Comment: @KJ which table are you expecting to find the relevant user code and date in?

Comment: All four of the tables @penguat

Comment: Ok. Please add that information to the question, along with the other information you have supplied in response to our questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I installed the "Oracle SQL Developer" software in my MacBook Pro to connect to my Microsoft SQL Server databases, however my "T-SQL" scripts that I wrote using the "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" didn't work, returning sintax errors.
I searched on the web and I discovered that the "Oracle SQL Developer" software don't works with T-SQL language from Microsoft.
Therefore, the "Oracle" included a tool ([Translation Scratch Editor](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/scratchlauncher-098387.html)) into their software to convert  the "T-SQL" language scripts to "PL/SQL" language.
To use this tool, access the menu **Tools > Migrate > Scratch Editor**, then you can put your T-SQL code and convert it to "PL/SQL" to run by the "Oracle SQL Developer".
I'm looking for a better solution, therefore this is the best solution i found for the moment.
I hope this tip can help you to solve your "problem" quickly.
The "PL/SQL" language have some diferences related to T-SQL, 
however you can replace easily with the "PL/SQL" sintaxes, searching for this on Google.
Sorry for my english, but i'm trying to help with the best i can.